# Shouldn't 'votes cast' be removed from the public user profile?

Tags: discussion, voting, profile-page

Considering votes are anonymous, it seems strange that there's a display showing all the vote casting statistics of a user.

Shouldn't this information be private?

I checked for other questions around Meta to find the reason, but was surprised no one mentioned this yet.

Tagged discussion rather than feature-request, since I personally don't mind a change or lack thereof. I'm just bringing the matter under attention. If it turns out a large number of people wants vote stats to be anonymous, I suppose this question could simply be retagged.

Answer (score 3):

> Considering votes are anonymous, it seems strange that there's a display showing all the vote casting statistics of a user.

Voting is still anonymous. The votes section is more of a summary - it doesn't show which posts that a particular user has voted on.

Even if you take [A Man A Plan...'s suggestion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/114375/133693) given that the page is highly cached, I really doubt if you'll be able to figure out who voted on what

Comment: What isn't anonymous, though, is your overall stats. For example, someone could have 1000 downvotes and 20 upvotes. This may well be information they do not enjoy to share with the whole site.

Comment: @Sathya read my name backwards ^_^

Comment: Votes cast is a good thing to identify bad users. In my opinion, votes should not be anonymous anyway. At least a comment attached to the vote should provide reasons.

Answer (score 1):

This is something I have wondered about.

If you are curious if a user will vote you down on a particular post you can keep refreshing the page to see if the vote count goes up or down.

**I do not** really see this as an issue, because even if someone were to do that, **HOW** would they know what post the user votes on, it would only be speculation.

And you know what happens when you speculate?

It makes *spec* out of *u* and a guy who is *late*

Answer (score 1):

```
Shouldn't this information be private?
```

Not necessarily because you cannot trace back any user's voting pattern. Unless you are a developer working at Stack Overflow, then *may be* you may know how the user has voted. Don't quote me on this.

```
I checked for other questions around Meta to find the reason, 
but was surprised no one mentioned this yet.
```

If it is a really serious issue *(which in this case it is not)*, I doubt something like this would have been overlooked in a site that has so many users and that too for so long. Since the votes cannot be backtracked, no one thinks there is any harm in showing the votes cast information.